# Change background color for all child elements without hiding images

Tags: css

I'm creating an application that edits the formatting of any webpage. I'm trying to change the background color of all the child divs of a selected div, but my current code makes images within the divs disappear.

```
.blah *:not(img) {
    background-color: #fffdd0 !important;
}
```

I tried using :not() to make the formatting not apply to images, but it didn't change anything. Is there a way to make the background color not apply to images or not hide images?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem: http://jsbin.com/yodiga/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Agree with @FabianSchultz https://jsfiddle.net/4b4Lam1o/

Comment: Ditto - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/JRLzQa

Comment: I guess that the problem is that the `img` is not a direct child of `.blah` but a `grandchild`. see my answer below ( + the comments ) maybe it will help you sort it out. let me know

Answer (score 0):

i think your `img`s are not `children` but they are `grandchildren` of your `.blah`div . that's why your code is not working. and so the parent of the `img` ( `.child` in my case ) gets the background and so a background appears under the image although the image doesn't get the `background-color` style

you could try something like this ( don't know your HTML structure or how complex it is )

```css
div *:not(.child) { background-color: #fffdd0 !important;}
.parent > .child *:not(img){ background-color: red !important;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<p>Child Text</p>
<h1>Child Heading</h1>
     <div class="child">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      <p>grandChild Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well yes. as i explained. even though the `img` doesn't get the `background-color` style, it's parent , which is a child of the `div ` gets the background-color. that's why a background-color appears under the image.

Comment: as i understand the question. he says that his current code made the images dissapear THEN he tried using `:not(img)` selector, but still, the background is applied to the img ( which isn't, it's applied to the parent of the image which is a child of the div )  `. Is there a way to make the background color not apply to images ` i answered his question. The problem is that the img is not a DIRECT child of the `div.blah` but a `.grandchild`

Comment: Well see from that point of view ... guessing it's a good answer since the question itself lacks of information ... will delete my comments and remove the downvote to avoid the spam of your answer . well done mate